# MySQL INSERT SELECT and get primary key values

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know if it's possible to INSERT records from a SELECT statement from a source table into a destination table, get the INSERT ID's and UPDATE a field on all the corresponding records from source table.

Take for example, the **destination** table 'payments':

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `txid` TEXT NULL,
    `amount` DECIMAL(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
    `worker` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The **source** table 'log':

```
CREATE TABLE `log` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `solution` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    `worker` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `amount` DECIMAL(16,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
    `pstatus` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
    `payment_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The "log" table contains multiple "micro-payments" for a completed task.  The purpose of the "payments" table is to consolidate the micro-payments into one larger payment:

```
INSERT INTO payments p (amount, worker)
                SELECT SUM(l.amount) AS total, l.worker FROM log l
                WHERE l.pstatus = "ready"
                AND l.payment_id IS NULL
                AND l.amount > 0
                GROUP BY l.worker
```

I'm not sure if clear from the code above, but I would like the field "payment_id" to be given the value of the insert id so that it's possible to trace back the micro-payment to the larger consolidated payment.

I could do it all client side (PHP), but I was wondering if there was some magical SQL query that would do it for me?  Or maybe I am going about it all wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql_insert_id() to get the id the inserted record.

> See [mysql_insert_id()](https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id)

But the above function is deprecated.

If you're using PDO, use [PDO::lastInsertId](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).

If you're using Mysqli, use [mysqli::$insert_id](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php).

Comment: May I quote the question: "I could do it all client side (PHP), but I was wondering if there was some magical SQL query that would do it for me?"

Comment: @fancyPants agree to your point. I failed to notice that and hurriedly replied to that.

Comment: more info may help us to help u

Answer (score 1):

Well, the linking column between the tables is the column `worker`. After you inserted your values, just do

```
UPDATE log l
INNER JOIN payments p ON l.worker = p.worker
SET l.payment_id = p.id;
```

and that's it. Or did I get the question wrong? Note, that the columns differ in the attribute signed/unsigned. You might want to change that.

Comment: That will work.  At first I questioned my decision to put the "worker" column in the payments table, but now (thanks to you) I see that it may actually be useful.

Comment: Probably one adjustment may be needed: 

    UPDATE log l
INNER JOIN payments p ON l.worker = p.worker
SET l.payment_id = p.id
WHERE l.pstatus = "ready"
   AND l.payment_id IS NULL
   AND l.amount > 0;

Comment: You are right, there's no need to update the whole table. Mine was just an example query. And just checking for `l.payment_id IS NULL` should be enough, actually, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use ORM in php as follows:

Look into [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/).

[Doctrine 1.2](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/en) implements Active Record. [Doctrine 2+](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.1/docs/en) is a DataMapper ORM.

Also, check out [Xyster](http://xyster.libreworks.com/). It's based on the Data Mapper pattern.

Also, take a look at [DataMapper vs. Active Record.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169832/data-mapper-vs-active-record)

Comment: May I quote the question: "I could do it all client side (PHP), but I was wondering if there was some magical SQL query that would do it for me?"